# ESLint rule being ignored

Tags: eslint

Just trying to have a SFC and ESLint is complaining

I haz rules in my `.eslinrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
    "no-console": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": [0, {
      "ignorePureComponents": true
    }],
    "comma-dangle": ["error", "never"],
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "never"]
  }
}
```

Even added the `/* eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "never"]*/` directly above the error, anyone else come across this?

What am I doing wrong

[image: ESLINT RULE PLZ!!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a disable-next-line just before your export:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line arrow-body-style
export onst Hi = () > {
 [...]
}
```

Maybe you could also try to replace `"arrow-body-style": ["error", "never"]` by `"arrow-body-style": "off"` in your .eslinrc.

By the way, if you just want to avoid this error, replace your code with the following:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Hi = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Hi;
```